# iPhone thinks textfields are empty after navigating through views (only on 8C148a)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, textfield

Hey guys, I have the strangest bug in my application I'm developing.

The thing is I have a login screen with two textfields that I create, add as subviews and release, all done in viewDidLoad.
Then as the user has logged in and logs out again, the textfields appear as normal but when the login-method is called it thinks the textfields are empty!

I have also only found this bug on iOS 4.2.1 (8C148a)

Furthemore the log show "Received memory warning. Level=1" and sometimes "Level=2" and this might be related but I don't know.

Can anyone help me? I'm quite lost...

My viewDidLoad:

```
userNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 85, 280, 30)];
userNameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
userNameTextField.placeholder = @"Användarnamn:";
userNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
userNameTextField.alpha = 0.9;
userNameTextField.opaque = YES;
userNameTextField.tag = 0;
userNameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
userNameTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
userNameTextField.textAlignment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
userNameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
userNameTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
userNameTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = FALSE;
[userNameTextField addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(textFieldDidReturn:) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 119, 280, 30)];
passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
passwordTextField.placeholder = @"Lösenord:";
passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
passwordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
passwordTextField.alpha = 0.9;
passwordTextField.opaque = NO;
passwordTextField.tag = 1;
passwordTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
passwordTextField.textAlignment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
passwordTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
passwordTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
[passwordTextField addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(textFieldDidReturn:) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

[self.view addSubview:userNameTextField];
[self.view addSubview:passwordTextField];

userNameTextField.delegate = self;
passwordTextField.delegate = self;

[userNameTextField release];
[passwordTextField release];
```

I also use the following methods:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[userNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];

[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event ];}

-(IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];}

-(BOOL)textFieldDidReturn:(UITextField *)textfield {
NSInteger nextTextFieldTag = textfield.tag + 1;
// Find next responding textfield
UIResponder *nextRespondingTextField = [textfield.superview viewWithTag:nextTextFieldTag];
if (nextRespondingTextField) {
    [nextRespondingTextField becomeFirstResponder];
} else {
    [self logInUser];
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
return NO;}

-(IBAction) logInUser {
// Popup alert
if (userNameTextField.text.length == 0 && passwordTextField.text.length == 0) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Vänligen ange användarnamn och lösenord." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Stäng." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} else if (passwordTextField.text.length == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Vänligen ange lösenord." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Stäng." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} else if (userNameTextField.text.length == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Vänligen ange användarnamn." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Stäng." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} else {

    PreschoolAppDelegate *globalAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Set global username and password
    globalAppDelegate.globalUserName = @"";
    globalAppDelegate.globalPassword = @"";
    globalAppDelegate.globalUserName = userNameTextField.text;
    globalAppDelegate.globalPassword = passwordTextField.text;




    // Clear variables


    globalAppDelegate.globalFirstname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalLastname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalChildFirstname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalChildSurname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalChildFullname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalSelectedChild = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalIdString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalChildIdString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    globalAppDelegate.globalSelectedChildId = [[NSString alloc] init];

    globalAppDelegate.globalWipChildList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalChildIdList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalChildList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalWipChildArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.tempGlobalAbsenceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.tempGlobalChildArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalAbsenceDescription = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalVacationDescription = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.tempGlobalVacationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalVacationWipChildArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalVacationStartDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalVacationEndDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalVacationStartDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    globalAppDelegate.globalVacationEndDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //
    // Start the fetch of the data from the rest service
    //

    userClient = [[GetUserListRestClient alloc] init];
    [userClient getUsers:self];

    [pendingLogin startAnimating];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector (checkIfConnFinished:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}}
```

Comment: Methinks you might want to simplify your design :P I suspect that if you didn't have all of those arrays, you wouldn't be losing your textfields.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems are in the property assignments like this:

```
globalAppDelegate.globalFirstname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
globalAppDelegate.globalWipChildList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This way your Strings and Arrays you created are never released. This caused the memory warnings. The good way is this:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
globalAppDelegate.globalFirstname = str;
[str release];
```

Or a shorter but not as good solution:

```
globalAppDelegate.globalWipChildList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I hope I could help.